# Inserting current date to MySql using Zend Date

Tags: php, zend-framework, datetime, date, zend-db

I have a website based on Zend Framework. There is a form for users to fill in and the entered data is inserted in the database.

The users don't enter the date/time. I would like to populate the data value based on the current date/time . The date **field** is of type **datetime**.

i'm constantly getting the following error message:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\wamp\www\CNFSORG\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
<?php $date = new Zend_Date(); ?>
```

also tried doing:

```
<?php $date = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'); ?>
<?php $date = new Zend_Db_Expr('CURDATE()'); ?>
```

I would be very grateful if someone could point me towards the right direction.

thanks in advance...

Comment: Well, there might be an all Zend solution way, but all DATETIME fields i use, i simply populate via `date('Y.m.d - H:i:s')`

Comment: cheers mate! That sorts me out!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Correct answer is

```
<?php $date = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'); ?>
```

You can try create a current timestamp from php with something like that

```
<?php  $date = new \DateTime(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'v done this for SqlServer, but i think that for MySql you just need to change the db-expression for the one you want.

```
$this->_colocation = new Application_Model_Colocation();
$solicitacao = $this->_colocation->find($post['hdnIdSolicitacao'])->current();
$solicitacao->data_chegada = new Zend_Db_Expr('getdate()');
$solicitacao->save();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Not exactly what i needed for but thanks for giving another dimension to what i was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

In your class of table use this code:

```
    $tme =new Zend_Date();
    $data['tme']=$tme->now();
    $this->insert($data);
```

If you have a column with `tme` name and type of `datetime` , this code will do what you want!